# Can iPhoto version 9.6 locate where photo was taken?

Tags: macbook-pro

iPhoto 9.6 
Can find the location where the photos were taken? I have several photos     of this person. The photos are originals.

Answer (score 1):

If you have taken the photos using an iPhone and location services was enabled for the camera app, then yes you should be able to see the location the photo was taken in iPhoto (as well as the new Photos app that shipped with OS X El Capitan).

To do so just highlight the photo and press `CMD + I` to bring up the inspector which will tell you the location, as well as a lot of info about the camera used.